# Why isn't my site showing on google.com but it's on top of another local Google search results?

Tags: seo, google-search

I'm trying to figure out why my site doesn't show up on `google.com` (from the United States). Even if I search for the domain name (`mysitename.com`) on `google.com`, the site doesn't show up. The only way to find the site is searching for `mysitename .com` (with a space).

However, if I try with a local Google site (spanish language), like `www.google.co.ve`, `www.google.cl`, `www.google.es` or `www.google.mx`, it shows up on top with a little effort.

The default site language is english (we also have spanish and portuguese versions).

The site is for an office space rental agency in the United States, therefore it should appear on `google.com` search results. I understand that some keywords could be very difficult to rank, but I don't understand why even using the site name, it doesn't show up.

I already setup the Google Webmaster Tools and chose the United States as site's target.

We use a hosting provider from Venezuela. Could be that the problem?

The site is `www.gmtbusinessplace.com`.

Comment: I think you need to provide your domain name?

Comment: Also when you say from United States what do you mean? The computer the search is being performed is in the USA or you're using .com (which is not the same)

Comment: www.gmtbusinessplace.com. The problem appears when you search from a computer in the USA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two days after setting Geo Target with Google Webmasters, Google seems to be ranking the site on top when you search for 'GMT Business Place'.

Thanks